# PowerApps: generate a number list from in a range?

Tags: powerapps

Is a very simple yet unsolved question.
How do i get something like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` in PowerApps starting from 0 and 7?
I'd like something like python `range(1,7)` but in power apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the new release that is being deployed this week (3.20065.16) there is a new function that does exactly that (it hasn't been documented yet, as it hasn't reached all regions). Depending on the region of your environment, you can use this function now, or should be able to do so by the end of the week:

```
Sequence(7) // Gives you the same as [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

or

```
Sequence(7, 0) // Gives you the same as [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

or even

```
Sequence(7, 1, 2) // Gives you the same as [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

You can check the version you are using in the File -> Account menu. If it is 3.20065 or larger, the Sequence function is available. If not, it will be soon when this version is deployed to your environment.